# Bootstrap CSS Omit Styling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use a small snippet I found to create a slide out tab on my page. Everything seems to work functionality wise however there is a style that is being applied from bootstrap that is breaking the look of it.

This is what it should look like when the following CSS is turned off:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[image]

However, when it is applied it breaks it:

[image]

Is there any way to prevent that css from being used on that DIV?

Comment: Have you access to bootstrap css?

Comment: I cant access it directly, no. We use it across multiple tools and only have access to my own stylesheet.

Comment: I think `#slideContent:before,#slideContent:after {box-sizing: content-box}` should do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving the element that has the gray background a .clearfix class.

Comment: I tried that, didnt seem to work. This was the simple snippet I was working with: http://return-true.com/2010/02/jquery-snippet-slideout-tab/